# Domain of derivative on open interval is open

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the derivative $f'$ exists at every point of a set $E \subseteq (a,b)$. Is it true that the domain $E$ of $f'$ is open?

And if it is not true, is it true that for every point $x \in E$ that has a neighborhood (possibly one-sided) in $E$, $x$ **must** have a two-sided neighborhood?

Here, a two-sided neighborhood of $x \in E$ means an open interval $(y, z) \subseteq E$ such that $x \in (y, z)$, while a one-sided neighborhood means a half-open interval $[y, z) \subseteq E$ or $(y, z] \subseteq E$ such that $x$ is contained within. A neighborhood is either one of the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: no. For instance, let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

$f'(0)$ exists, but $f$ s continuous only in $0$. The same trick works if you take a continuous function $g(x)$ that is nowhere differentiable and multiply it by $x^2$: its derivative will exists only in $0$.

Second question: I think what you want is something like this: take a continuous function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that it is nowhere differentiable. Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2&\text{if } x>0\\x^2g(x)&\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$$

In this case, $E=[0,+\infty)$ and $x=0$ fails your test.

Comment: This is nice! That $x^2$ trick is great and I think I managed to prove it. I haven't read about everywhere continuous functions that are nowhere differentiable but a quick googling gave me the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) =0, x \le 0, f(x) = x/(x+1), x>0.$ Let $r_1,r_2,\dots $ be the rationals. Then

$$g(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}f(x-r_n)$$

is a continuous function on $\mathbb {R}$ such that $f'(x)$ exists iff $x$ is irrational.